# Problem with views recent comments block

Tags: views, comments

I have a problem with the recent comments block created with Views. I have overridden the view fields in the view template (views-view-fields--comments-recent--block.tpl.php) and printed out the fields:

```
print '<div class="subj">'. $fields['subject']->content .'</div>';
print '{ <span> '.$fields['name']->content. '</span>' .', '. '<span>'. $fields['timestamp']->content .'</span> }';
```

It displays the name of user that created that node. For example, I've created a node titled "blahblahblah" and I added a comment on my node; the block displays "blahblah - posted by heihachi." If another user (jessica) posts a comment in that node, the block still displays " blahblah - posted by heihachi," not "by jessica."
Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the title and author being shown belongs to the node not the comment. There are some options under the comment group of a views fields or you can use a relationship to specify the node's author or the comment's author.